# Calculating $\mathbb{E}[2\sin (\pi Z)|\cos (\pi Z)]$ when $Z$ is uniform on $[0,2]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, density-function

I am trying to calculate the following conditional expectation.

Let Z be a uniformly distributed random variable on the closed interval $[0, 2]$.
Define $X = \cos(\pi Z)$ and $Y = 2\sin(\pi Z)$.
Calculate $\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \mathbb{E}[Y|\sigma(X)]$.

I have tried multiple approaches, but don't know how to proceed since I am only familiar with the standard techniques for calculating the conditional expectation, i.e. when Y is independent of X, Y is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$ or if a joint density $f(x,y)$ exists. The first two parts don't apply here and since X and Y aren't independent I don't know how to calculate the joint density.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three approaches to this problem.

1. **Intuition**. There is no joint density of $X$ and $Y$ with respect to the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, it should be clear that $(X,Y/2)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The unit circle is symmetric in both the $x$ and $y$ axes of the plane, so it follows that $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=0$.
2. **Kolmogorov conditional expectation**. You can try the approach described in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829813/280385), which is as follows. We know that $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=g(X)$ for some Borel measurable function $g$. Now use the defining property of the conditional expectation to pin down what $g$ actually is. I haven't worked out all the details but I think this approach should work.
3. **Regular conditional probabilities**. This is the approach hinted at by @AntonioSpeltzu but without much detail. It is more intuitive than the second approach, but requires the additional machinery of regular conditional probabilities, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498338/280385) (general theory) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603295/86998) (how to use the theory in practice). They allow us to give meaning to statements such as $$P\left(Y/2=\frac{1}{2} | X=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$ This approach will get you the right answer, but is not strictly necessary because the question only asks about conditional expectations rather than condtional probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified case from:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603110/how-to-calculate-px-in-a-sinx-y

Here: $P[Z\in A|X=x]=\frac{1}{2}(I_A(arccos(x)/\pi)+I_A((2\pi-arccos(x))/\pi))$
Therefore: $E[X|Y]=E[Y|X]=0$

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Brief and good, twice as good.

Answer (score 1):

I have an upcoming exam, so I wanted to tackle this question as an exercise. We use the second approach suggested by the accepted answer.

Let $X=\cos(\pi Z)$ and $Y=\sin(\pi Z)$ where $Z \sim \text{Uniform}([0,2])$. Let $h(X)$ be a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$. Let $u : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded and measurable (or non-negative and measurable, it does not matter for this approach). It must hold that

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y u(X)] = \mathbb{E}[h(X) u(X)]$$

With this in mind, we calculate:

$$ \begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[Yu(X)] &= \frac{1} {2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)u(cos(x)) \; dx \\\\ &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)u(cos(x)) \;dx + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sin(x)u(cos(x)) \;dx \right) \\\\ &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)u(cos(x)) \;dx + \int_0^\pi\sin(2\pi - x)u(cos(2\pi - x)) \;dx \right) \\\\ &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)u(cos(x)) \;dx + \int_0^\pi-\sin(x)u(cos(x)) \;dx \right) \\\\ &=0 \end{align*} $$

Since this holds for all $u$, it follows that $h(X)=0$ a.e.